# How do I install the latest OpenOffice?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, openoffice.org

As a new Ubuntu user, I have installed a few apps through the Terminal.

I have tried to follow several, albeit outdated, threads that explain how to install OpenOffice, but I cannot get it to work. It would be really helpful if someone would provide me with the necessary commands for it to work.

Comment: I believe OpenOffice has largely been superseded by LibreOffice.

Comment: To add to that : OpenOffice is not secure nowaday. [There is not enough developer to do the most basic security update anymore](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/09/openoffice-after-years-of-neglect-could-shut-down/) : they almost all moved to LibreOffice. Don't install OpenOffice.

Comment: Oracle is using the Apache and Eclipse foundations as mausoleums for their abandoned open source software.

Comment: OpenOffice is called LibreOffice now. It's preinstalled in Ubuntu.

Comment: @fkraiem - Can you expand this and make that an answer because I think it's probably the right one...

Comment: Was it not announced recently that they were planning to cancel the OpenOffice project?

Answer (score 27):

- We use Libreoffice. It basically is OpenOffice but with a license that is suited. OpenOffice has a license that is too restrictive for Ubuntu to be of use (see below).
- Besides that: Ubuntu is not about using the latest version but the most stable version at the release of the OS. Security wise it is better to stick with the versions Ubuntu supplies. Security related fixes are provided when those are found and fixed.

Nevertheless ...

- You need to remove LibreOffice 1st and since there is no personal archive for Openoffice you need to [download](http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html) it from their website (pick 64-bit DEB). Software is provided by a DEB so you can download it and use our Software Center to install it by doubleclicking the finished download; or you can pick the `tar.gz` download and it will have installation instructions inside the installer on how to install it (see the readme regarding installation inside the package).

But why go through this trouble?  Since there is a [licensing issue](http://www.howtogeek.com/187663/openoffice-vs.-libreoffice-whats-the-difference-and-which-should-you-use/) I would always opt for LibreOffice.

> This isn’t an accident. OpenOffice’s sidebar code was copied and incorporated into LibreOffice. The Apache OpenOffice project uses the Apache License, while the LibreOffice uses a dual LGPLv3 / MPL license. The practical result is LibreOffice can take OpenOffice’s code and incorporate it into LibreOffice — the licenses are compatible.
>
> On the other hand, LibreOffice has some features — like font embedding — that don’t appear in OpenOffice. This is because the two different licenses only allow a one-way transfer of code. LibreOffice can incorporate OpenOffice’s code, but OpenOffice can’t incorporate LibreOffice’s code. This is the result of the different licenses the projects chose.

Basically: LibeOffice will always have more features than OpenOffice.

**Regarding LibeOffice**

- [LibreOffice](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice) provides a native [Debian installer](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=5.2&lang=en-US) so you can use Software Center to install it. And there is also a [personal archive](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for the really bleeding edge ...

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
  sudo apt update
  ```

  You can also install specific versions newer than what Ubuntu provides by replacing the 1st command with ...

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-2
  ```

and replacing the `4-2` by the version you want.

---

By the way: you do NOT need to remove LibreOffice or OpenOffice if you want to install a newer version of Libreoffice or of OpenOffice. You do need to remove the other one if you want to switch between them or need to remove a version that as higher than the one you want to install (and disable the newer version when installing the older version).

Comment: If you want to have both OpenOffice and Libreoffice, you can install LibreOffice via snap:

    sudo snap install libreoffice

Comment: LibreOffice is as much OpenOffice as OSX is BSD. The code has considerably improved (a massive code cleanup was done), they're much better at features updates and bug fixes (including security fixes - see http://lwn.net/Articles/699755/ for a mess that happened this year with OOo).

Comment: I don't know anything about the split, but in your answer you say "OOo has a license that is too restrictive" but then quote from a source that paints LibreOffice as having more restrictive licensing (since it only permits one-way reuse). I promise I'm not trying to start a holy war `:)`, but I found the presence of those two statements a little confusing. (I'm guessing the "OOo is too restrictive" has something to do with patents, or something?)

Comment: No it has to do with the license, not patents. @muru I did not mean that comparison for the internal differences. From the users POV they still look mostly identical :)

Comment: Although this answer is correct based on the question asked, I don't think it answers the question the user meant to ask.  I think the user (because of the mention of outdated threads and being a new user) doesn't know about the Open Office / Libre Office split and is using "Open Office" as a generic term for office suite.  The questioner can confirm, but that's my guess.

Comment: "We use Libreoffice. It basically is OpenOffice but with a license that is suited." This is not a true statement, LibreOffice on Linux and Windows is laggy and buggy almost to the point of it being unusable. I have been struggling with LibreOffice for the past few months on LinuxMint and finally had enough today.. After purging it all from my machine and installing openOffice all the annoying bugs and laggyness have vanished.

Comment: Linux mint is the problem ;) LibreOffice works flawlessly here. We have it running on 12.04, 16.04 and 17.10. The codebase for LO and OO is pratically the same. LO though has more features (since the license only can be used 1 way and not both ways).

Answer (score 7):

1. You have to remove the installed versions of either libreOffice or openoffice:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libreoffice* openoffice*
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```

   (or)

   Open the Ubuntu Software Center and type libreoffice . click on uninstall to uninstall.
2. Download OpenOffice from its official website.The download file will be in *.tar.gz format.

   For 32 bit Ubuntu, Debian:

   ```
   wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   ```

   For 64 bit**

   ```
   wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   ```
3. Click on “Extract here”

   For 32 bit:

   ```
   tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   ```

   For 64 bit:

   ```
   tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   ```
4. Now open the Terminal and change the directory to the location where your Extracted Open Office file is present.Just type “cd” followed by drag and dropping the “DEBS” folder or manually do it.

   ```
   cd en-GB/DEBS
   ```
5. Type the following commands to install OpenOffice package files.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb    
   cd desktop-integration    
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

Try `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*` if you face any errors when installing open office

Comment: The offer debs on the site so why go the hard way?

Comment: Indeed: https://www.openoffice.org/download/  However there are many deb files to install so `dpkg -i *.deb` is much easier... unless i missed a general install helper?

Answer (score 3):

Download openoffice https://www.openoffice.org/es/descargar/

uncompress.
In terminal

```
cd en/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

execute

```
cd /opt/openoffice4/program
./soffice
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use Libreoffice in Linux.since there is no open office in Ubuntu repositories you should download it from official site. Download correct package from here http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html

Extract the downloaded archive. Since it is an archive, you need to extract it. You can do that using your package program, or you can do it using this terminal command:

`tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_3.4.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_ar.tar.gz`

***You may need to change the name in the text above to fit your package.***

type the following command into the terminal:

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

You will be required to provide an administrative password to run this command.

The executable file is located here: `/opt/openoffice.org3/program/soffice`

now create luancher for this excutable file from this [site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-deskt).