# What do I need to install to be able to use OpenOffice?

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

I would like to install OpenOffice because I like it better than LibreOffice. However, my dependencies are not satisfied for the writer module. Apparently OpenOffice-EN-US is a dependency of itself.

I have provided a screenshot in the hopes that someone can tell me what packages I need to install (Preferably not all of them).

[image: screenshot showing some deb files in a folder]

Comment: *"However, my dependencies are not satisfied for the writer module. Apparently OpenOffice-EN-US is a dependency of itself."* Can you **[edit]** this to give *way* more details? Exactly how did you install it? Did you run commands in a terminal? If so, please give the commands and their complete exact output. Is this from a PPA? Did you *manually* download a .deb or other file? If so, from where? If you downloaded it yourself, was it [from here](http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html)? If not, what are you doing instead (and why)? If so, what's the file's name and how did you use it?

Comment: i would strongly advise to stay with LibreOffice: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841148/how-do-i-install-the-latest-openoffice#comment1287855_841148 -- maybe we can help you with this, if you tell us what you liked better at OpenOffice...?